# php automatic redirect to a page after some seconds' delay

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am making a register form and when you succesfully fill in all the fields, it redirects to `thank_you_register.php`. But I want that after a few seconds, the `thank_you_register.php` page automatically redirects to another page. How do I do this?
The HTML code is this:

```
<form class="register form" action="../app/controller/authController.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="region" id="">
                    <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
                    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="" placeholder="First Name">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['first_name_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['first_name_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['first_name_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="" placeholder="Last Name">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['last_name_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['last_name_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['last_name_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['email_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['email_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="confirm_email" id="" placeholder="Confirm E-mail Address">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['confirm_email_error'])) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['confirm_email_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['confirm_email_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="" placeholder="Password">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['password_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['password_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['password_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['confirm_password_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['confirm_password_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['confirm_password_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="age" id="" placeholder="Age">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['age_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['age_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['age_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="type" value="Register" class="register button">
            </div>
        </form>
```

And the PHP code of the form is this:

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'Register') {

    $i=0;
    $names = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'confirm_email', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'age');
    foreach($names as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {

            $_SESSION[$field.'_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
            $i++;
        }

        else
        {
          unset($_SESSION[$field.'_error']);
          $user->redirect('register.php');
        }

    }

    if (sizeof($names) == $i) {
        $user->redirect('register.php');
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] != $_POST['confirm_email']) {
        $_SESSION['confirm_email_error'] = "E-mail Address does not match!";
        exit();
    }

    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']) {
        $_SESSION['confirm_password_error'] = "Password does not match!";
        exit();
    }

    function add($region, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $confirm_email, $password, $confirm_password, $age) {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $database = Database::getInstance();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`
                (`region`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `confirm_email`, `password`, `confirm_password`, `age`)
                VALUES (:region, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :confirm_email, :password, :confirm_password, :age)";

        $stmt = $database->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':region', $region);
        $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':confirm_email', $confirm_email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':confirm_password', $confirm_password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':age', $age);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    $user->redirect('');
```

I haven't filled out the `$user->redirect('');` because i don't know what should be in there yet.

And the HTML code for the `thank_you_register` page is this:

```
<?php require realpath(__DIR__ . '/header.php'); ?>

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="messageBox">
        <div class="MB_head">
            <h2>Thank You!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="MB_content">
            <p>You are registered.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to do automatic redirect.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://domain.com/'" />

Comment: you can't (reasonably) do this with PHP - you'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/" />
```

or (via javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function() { 
       window.location.href = "http://example.com";
   },5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Use location.replace to not break the back button - and a setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

In thank_you_register.php add this script

```
<script>setTimeout(function() { location.replace("otherpage.html")},3000);</script>
```

to replace the thankyouregister after 3 seconds.

**NOTE:** I use `location.replace` to not break the back button from thankyouregister

Comment: I'm sorry... By "not break the back button", you want the history path to be from the final page to the original page (bypassing `thank_you`), right?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

In your **thank_you_register.php** page put this into your `<head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://your_site.com/">
```

The 5 are the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use javascript to do that

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Comment: Use location.replace to not break the back button

Comment: What do you mean ? you still can push the back button and go back to your page with a window.location

Comment: If I am on "http://www.yoururl.com"; in your script, I will keep getting pushed back to "http://www.yoururl.com"; if I push the back button

Comment: this is weird, i just tried and i came back to my original page

Comment: If you put <script>window.location = "page3.html";</script> in page 2 of your site, you have to click the dropdown and select page1 to get to page 1 of your site from page3.html

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript for this. It offers a much nicer user experience.

Example:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="messageBox">
        <div class="MB_head">
            <h2>Thank You!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="MB_content">
            <p>You are registered.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Redirecting you back to the home page...click <a href="/url/to/redirect/to">here</a> if you are not automatically redirected</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
   setTimeout(function () { 
        window.location.href = "/url/to/redirect/to";
   }, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds until it calls function

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Php script to achieve what you stated above

```
  <?php
      header('Location: http://www.example1.com/');
       sleep(20);
      header('Location: http://www.example2.com/');

 ?>
```